# Searching for documents to get links

Tags: python, web-scraping

This script goes to a website, enters a name, and clicks search just fine. Once it gets through the initial search, I need to find all the documents that contain a certain word such as "deed", then find the link that goes with that "deed", then put the links inside a pdf, and save the file.

I can't provide an XPath because each time you have a document they have their own path. So I'm trying to get it to scrap the page and locate them all.

Right now when it prints, it just returns empty. I know it's the XPaths but cant figure it out..

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

```py
while True:

    # Find the rows that contain the word "deed" in the 4th column
    row_elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//table[@id="f"]//tr[td[contains(text(), "deed")]]')

    # Extract the links from the rows
    links = [row.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//td[1]/a').get_attribute("href") for row in row_elements]
    print(links)

    # Iterate through the links and download the PDFs
    for link in links:
        # Get the PDF content from the link
        response = requests.get(link)

        # Create a PDF file object from the PDF content
        file = io.BytesIO(response.content)

        # Create a PDF reader object
        reader = P

# Close the web browser 
driver.close()
```

Comment: Hello, please reduce your code to few lines that you receive empty values and add a simple webpage data to clarify question more. Good luck.

Comment: Please add a tiny sample of `html` data and I try to test your `//table[@id="f"]//tr[td[contains(text(), "deed")]]` to see why it's empty.

Comment: The problem is I don't know which path to grab. Each time a document is listed it has its on Xpath. I need to be able to locate all of them without me manually doing it. This is the Xpath to the column that list the document types /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[1]/table/thead/tr/th[5]/div; This is the Xpath for one of the actually documents /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]. Once it finds those documents I need it to pull the links that go on separate column

Comment: we can't figure out the common XPath without some of the relevant HTMLs

Comment: ss="tablesorter" id="doc"><thead><tr><th>Instrument #</th><th>Date Recorded</th><th>Name</th><th>Party Role</th><th>Doc Type</th><th>Other Name</th

Comment: So you're looking for table elements which has attribute id `f` contain `tr` `td`  whit text element `dead` in it?

Comment: If you want help, you have to add sample data in a sample text, and sample that you want to be extracted from it. In other way, it is too hard to help you. Good luck.